# Text field tag search issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

Hello everybody i'm trying to search a column from another table with id hide using text_field_tag

In my view policy_vehicles i have text_field_tag and want to search by motor

My tables

```
Vehicles
      |id|       |motor|    |plate|
    integer    varchar(255)  varchar(255)
       1        MOTOR1        PLATE1
       2        MOTOR2        PLATE2
       3        MOTOR3        PLATE3

Policy_vehicles
   |id|       |vehicle_id| 
    integer      integer
     1              1 
     2              2
     3              3
     4              2
```

Here is my controller

```
class PolicyManagement::PolicyController < ApplicationController

  def generate_print_per_vehicle
      @motor =Vehicle.find(:all,:conditions=>['motor =?' ,params[:search_motor] ] )
      @policies= PolicyVehicle.find(:all,:conditions=>['vehicle_id= ?',params[:search_motor] ] ) 
  end

end
```

Here is my model

```
class PolicyVehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :vehicle
end

class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :policy_vehicles
end
```

Here is my view where i'm trying to find by a column from another table

```
<% form_tag :controller=>"policy_management/policy",:action=>"generate_print_per_vehicle" do %>
 Motor:
   <%= text_field_tag "search_motor",params[:search_motor] %>
   <%= submit_tag "Buscar", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

My logs

```
 Vehicle Load (0.1ms)   SELECT * FROM `vehicles` WHERE (motor ='4D56UCCR5811') 
 PolicyVehicle Load (0.3ms)   SELECT * FROM `policy_vehicles` WHERE (vehicle_id= '4D56UCCR5811')
```

It should be search like this

```
 SELECT * FROM `vehicles` WHERE (motor ='4D56UCCR5811' and id =1) 
 SELECT * FROM `policy_vehicles` WHERE (vehicle_id= '1')
```

I tried this but is not working

```
 #controller
 @vehicle = Vehicle.find(:all,:conditions=>['motor =?' ,params[:search_motor] ])
 @policies = PolicyVehicle.find(:all, :conditions => ['vehicle_id = ?  ', @vehicle.id])

#logs
Vehicle Load (17.2ms)   SELECT * FROM `vehicles` WHERE (motor ='4D56UCCR5811') 
PolicyVehicle Load (0.3ms)   SELECT * FROM `policy_vehicles` WHERE (vehicle_id = 70353663367520 )
```

Well i did a select_tag, but i want to write the motor, not select like this

```
<%= select_tag "search_motor",options_for_select(@vehicle.collect {|t| [t.motor.to_s ,t.id]}, params[:search_motor].to_i )  %>
```

Please someone can help me ? 
I will really appreciate help

Comment: Post your `db/schema.rb`. What is the field type for `vehicles.motor`?

Comment: It's vachar....(string) i edited my post can you read it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using find with `:all` specified, you'll get an array of vehicles back, even if that array is size 1.  So instead of asking for `@vehicle.id` you'd have to ask for something like `@vehicle[0].id`:

```
PolicyVehicle.find(:all, :conditions => ['vehicle_id = ?  ', @vehicle[0].id])
```

But if you don't need the `@motor` array for any other purpose, you should be able use one query with `:join` to go directly to the record you want:

```
PolicyVehicle.find(:all, :joins => :vehicle, :conditions => ['motor =?',params[:search_motor]])
```

Comment: Oh man ... you did it worked perfect .

You are the master!!. :)
MANY THANKS""

Answer (score 1):

If you're "searching" against VARCHAR(255) you'll likely want to use `LIKE` instead of `=`.

```
@vehicle = Vehicle.find(:all,:conditions => ['motor LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search_motor]}%" ])
@policies= PolicyVehicle.find(:all, :conditions => ['vehicle_id= ?', @vehicle.id])
```

Also, if you're running Rails 3 or 4, you'll probably want to stop using `find(:all, ...)` and instead use `where(..)`.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions

> 2.3.1 Equality Conditions
>
> Client.where(locked: true) The field name can also be a string:
>
> Client.where('locked' => true) In the case of a belongs_to
>   relationship, an association key can be used to specify the model if
>   an Active Record object is used as the value. This method works with
>   polymorphic relationships as well.

This is the log:

```
 Vehicle Load (15.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `vehicles` WHERE (motor = '%M16A1418981%') 
 PolicyVehicle Load (0.3ms)   SELECT * FROM `policy_vehicles` WHERE (vehicle_id= 70353666460940)
```

Comment: Well i tried your code but still not getting the id of the motor searched

Comment: i should have SELECT * FROM `vehicles` WHERE (motor ='4D56UCCR5811' and id =1).


>>>>SELECT * FROM `policy_vehicles` WHERE (vehicle_id= '1')

Comment: Why do you need `id = 1`? If you know the `id`, why not just load it directly? `@vehicle = Vehicle.find(params[:id])` would get you that without extra conditions.

Comment: Well i want to write the name of the "motor"

Comment: Farley  i want to get the id of the table vehicle to use to use it in the condition policy_vehicles